# What are the analogues of momentum, inertia and angular momentum for energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, mass-energy, invariants

If Energy and mass are the same thing, then is it logical to look for analogous (duals) of properties of one in another?  or there is there any conceptual framework that such questions make any sense? are there any properties from mass to energy or backwards that remain invariant? or just equivalence of energy and mass is where all the relationships in the intrinsic properties end?

Not trying to make this a philosophy question, only wondering if this concepts have a place in physics or have been previously dealt with in a any topics of physics.

Comment: It's a myth. Mass and energy are not equivalent: "*The Energy-momentum relation was first established by Paul Dirac in 1928 under the form $E=\sqrt {c^{2}p^{2}+(m_{o}c^{2})^{2}}+V$, where V is the amount of potential energy.*" - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-momentum_relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically no. Energy and mass are not dual to each other in the sense that electric and magnetic fields are dual. Each of the conserved quantities you mention (momentum, angular momentum, and energy) is conserved because of a symmetry, through Noether's theorem. E.g., angular momentum is conserved because of the rotational symmetry of the laws of physics. One symmetry, one conserved quantity.

Answer (score 1):

"If Energy and mass are the same thing," Sorry, but they're not. Mass is a type of energy. Specifically, an object's mass is the amount of energy that remains after you bring that object to rest.

Energy has two defining properties that make it unique. First, it is the only conserved quantity in nature that does not have an anti-quantity associated with it. This is one of the facts that is part of the third law of thermodynamics. Every other conserved quantity that I've heard of has both a quantity and anti-quantity. Left-bound momentum is anti-right-bound momentum, for example, allowing you to generate as much rightbound momentum as you like by balancing it out with the same amount of leftbound.

Second, energy is the quantity that is conserved because the laws of physics are invariant under translations in time. Noether's theorem says that every conserved quantity corresponds to a symmetry, and vice versa. So, momentum is from the fact that space is invariant under translations, and angular momentum is conserved becasaue space/the laws of physics are invariant under rotations.